# Как передать координаты вершин списком simple_draw

Tags: python-3.x, функции, simple-draw

Помогите понять как передать координаты четырёх точек в списке - для первого значения функции lines  библиотеки simple_draw. Как только этот список не создавал, ни чего на получается. Потратил несколько дней и без результата.

Функция lines из библиотеке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если внимательно посмотреть на [исходный код](https://github.com/suguby/simple_draw/blob/master/simple_draw.py) библиотеки и найти там функцию `lines`, можно увидеть в ней такой код:

```
converted_point_list = [pos.to_screen() for pos in point_list]
```

Тут видно, что к каждому элементу списка `point_list` применяется метод `to_screen()`, посмотрим на него. Оказывается, это метод класса `Point`:

```
class Point:
    """
        Класс точки экрана
    """

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self._x = random_number(1, resolution[0]) if x is None else int(x)
        self._y = random_number(1, resolution[1]) if y is None else int(y)

    def to_screen(self):
        return int(self._x), resolution[1] - int(self._y)
```

Соответственно, в `lines` нужно передать список объектов типа `Point`. Например:

```
point_list = [Point(10,20), Point(30,40)]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @CrazyElf           Стоило спросить здесь и сам до ответа додумался, буквально, через 3 минуты.